# how to pass a Scala function to another function as a function?

Tags: function, scala

I'm just not understanding how to build a function from previous functions.

For example, `math.min()` function that takes the minimum of two numbers. What if I wanted to create a function `min3Z(a:int, b:int, c:Int)`? How would I build this from `min`?

Comment: See example in [reduceLeft code](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.6/src/library/scala/collection/TraversableOnce.scala#L163)

Answer (score 7):

Your question is unclear. Are you simply trying to utilize `math.min()` in `min3Z()`? Because in that case, you can do:

```
def min3Z(a: Int, b: Int, c: Int) = math.min(a, math.min(b, c))
```

If you want to pass in an arbitrary function (for example, making it so you can specify max or min), you can specify a function as a parameter:

```
def min3Z(a: Int, b: Int, c: Int, f: (Int, Int) => Int) = f(a, f(b, c))
```

The syntax `(Int, Int) => Int` in Scala is the type for a function that takes two parameters of type `Int` and returns a result of type `Int`. `math.min()` and `math.max()` both fit this criteria.

This allows you to call min3Z as `min3Z(1, 2, 3, math.min)` or `min3Z(1, 2, 3, math.max)`. It's even possible to make a version of `min3Z()` that takes an arbitrary number of `Int`s and an arbitrary `(Int, Int) => Int` function, but that's beyond the scope of your question.

Answer (score 0):

If implementing `min` for three values is your specific case you may want to generalize to an arbitrary number of arguments by using a variadic (aka varargs) function as follows:

```
def min(xs: Int*): Int = xs.min
```

The variadic syntax is denoted by the `*` symbol after the type declaration--`Int` in this case. This way all the following calls would work:

```
min(1, 2)
min(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, -1)
// and so on...
```

Talking about being generic you could also write an even more generic `min` that accepts any *numeric* type, not only `Int` ones:

```
def min[T : Numeric](xs: T*): T = xs.reduceLeft(implicitly[Numeric[T]].min)
```

An use it as follows:

```
min(1, 2, 3, 4)
min(1.2, 3.4, 5.6, 4.2)
```